# In jquery UI autocomplete feature add a buttons at the end of each item in the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-autocomplete

[image]
I have created the list using jQuery Ui autocomplete now wanted to display 3 buttons to the end of each item in the list, I have tried the following code for single button but its not working for me,kindly guide me for this.

I have used _renderItem to render the button at the end of each item in the list.

```
...).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul,item){
var addTobag = $('<input/>').attr({type:'button', name:'bag',class:'btn btn-primary' , value:'Add to bag',style:'float : right'});
return $('<li></li>').append('<span>' + item.label + addTobag'</span>' )
};
```

It displays me error as undefined[object object]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You appear to be adding Objects to a String. It's also not clear why you are adding Buttons to a Autocomplete.

Comment: I suspect you want may want to consider the following Demo: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that adds Button elements to your list for Autocomplete.

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"
  ];
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $("<li>")
      .append("<div>" + item.label + "<input type='button' name='bag' class='btn btn-primary' value='Add to bag' style='float: right;' /></div>")
      .appendTo(ul);
  };
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Since the User must Select the item, it sort of defeats the Button click.

I would advise you look at https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple With this example, they can select a list of items to add as the Value that is later submitted.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the issue comes in this functionality is I cannot click on bag button only, whenever I click on a button the url value associated with product(i.e label) gets hited

Comment: @user15950409 that is the expected behavior. Users should click an item to select it from the list. IT was not designed to have a User click a Button in the List.